# Compare a MySQL column with parameter variable from method

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to compare the email with the parameter variable also called email. I am getting an error saying "`Parameter ?email must be defined`" I also tried using `@email`:

```
internal bool ValidateUser(string email, string password, bool rememberMe)
{
    bool valid = false;

    using (_msqlCon = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        _msqlCon.Open();
        _query = "SELECT Password, RememberMe FROM RegisteredUsers WHERE Email = ?email";

        using (_command = new MySqlCommand(_query, _msqlCon))
        {
            MySqlDataReader reader = _command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader["Password"].Equals(password)) { valid = true;  }
        }
    }
    return valid;
}
```

How can I check if the column Email is the same as the one given as parameter?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how you use the `email` parameter in the query, the answer is that you add it to the command object as a parameter. Try this:

```
internal bool ValidateUser(string email, string password, bool rememberMe)
{
    bool valid = false;
    using (_msqlCon = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString)) {
        _msqlCon.Open();
        _query = "SELECT Password, RememberMe FROM RegisteredUsers WHERE Email = @Email";

        using (_command = new MySqlCommand(_query, _msqlCon)) {
            _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", email);
            MySqlDataReader reader = _command.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader["Password"].Equals(password)) {
                valid = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return valid;
}
```

See [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html) for more information on how to use parameters.

Comment: Actually my posted solution didn't behave as I expected, so I deleted it. My solution resulted in weird behavior with the MySqlDataReader. So your solution was the one I needed